# Edit role color from RGB input

Tags: discord.py

Trying to let users set their very own color for their username

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def test(ctx, r = Option(int, required=True), g = Option(int, required=True), b = Option(int, required=True)):
    guild = ctx.guild
    for role in ctx.author.roles:
        await role.delete()
    role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="test")
    await role.edit(colour=Colour.from_rgb(r, g, b))
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.respond(f"_ _",ephemeral=True)
```

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/colour.py", line 126, in from_rgb
    return cls((r << 16) + (g << 8) + b)
                ~~^^~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'
```

I don't understand what's wrong, there are no strings anywhere, only integrals.

EDIT : Found it, it's because I typed "r = Option" instead of "r : Option"

Comment: Glad you found the error. Even so, I suggest you receive a hex code instead of r, g, b parameters, making the command simpler to use.